# How to assign different attributes in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 6 fields and I want to set their attributes in model. 3 _print fields are auto saved like this.

```
def field1=(value)
  @number = Phoner::Phone.parse(value)
  write_attribute(:field1, @number.to_s)
end

def field1_print=(value)
  write_attribute(:field1_print, print_format(@number))
end
```

And I have these methods for field2, field2_print, field3 and field3_print. Can I put these methods in some .each method and iterate so I don't have these method duplication?

Comment: Try this `self.attributes.each do |name, value| do something(name, value) end`

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tested it, but you can frame like this:

```
["1", "2", "3"].each do |action|
  define_method("field#{action}=(value)") do |argument|
    @number = Phoner::Phone.parse(argument)
    write_attribute("field#{action}", @number.to_s)
  end
end


["1", "2", "3"].each do |action|
  define_method("field#{action}_print=(value)") do |argument|
    write_attribute("field#{action}_print, print_format(@number))
  end
end
```